# Need better management of display sleep times in Fedora 17. How to do?

Tags: linux, sleep, power-management, display-settings

I am using Fedora 17  64bit on an AMD quad core machine.  My use is home use with some power user thrown in (spreadsheets, photo editing, music creating). ALL my Television viewing is done by streaming.

So far can't find a way to set sleep time for my monitor.

Would love to be able to select easily a:

- "movie" setting for when Im using the computer to watch a DVD or Stream a Movie.  That would put it in a temporary 3 hour no sleep mode on the monitor.
- "Episode viewing" setting for when your viewing a typical one hour TV show
- "custom viewing" for those days your not sure exactly what your going to do- just type in how many hours you want the monitor to not sleep.

All above are reverted back to Gnome defaults when:

- selected time of one of the above end
- when the user logs off

Comment: This sounds more than a rant than a question. Also, if you're only now learning Linux, don't use Fedora, try Mint or Ubuntu instead. Fnally, Linux (as much as I love it) is simply not as good for what you call "power user" as other OSs. Spreadsheets are OK with libreoffice, GIMP is admittedly great but OSX is better for photo editing, ANYTHING is better for music, there is no equivalent to reason/logic or qbase on linux.

Comment: being that less than a year ago I was basically homeless and in debt well above my head (my business went under) Im digging out now soooooooo finances make it Linux or nothing......... so linux it is. Used Ubunto before.  It is a toss up between Mint and Fedora.  both are listed as having good qualities.  From what I read it looked like Fedora may be best overall to my needs so..that is what I loaded and will go with that for a while. Thanx for the ideas. Have used OO for years e so Libreoffice will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a video player which disables the screen saver and display power management while playing video. An example of such a video player would be vlc. When it's playing, the screen will not turn off nor start a screensaver, even if the video is paused.

Comment: Thank you but that only works when a stream is available that can be reached via a link direct.  That's not the case with websites like Hulu,  Sidereel, netflix etc. unless Im missing something and I could be.  What do you suggest?